# How to use fsolve in MATLAB for only one of the variables?

Tags: matlab

I have a function

```
func(u1,u2,t)
```

now I want to find the value of u2 when

```
0 = func(u1, u2, t)
```

where `u1=a` and `t=b` are known values. How can I do this (with `fsolve` or other functions) in MATLAB? Thanks

Comment: Provided that `func` returns a scalar you should probably use `fzero` rather than `fsolve`. `fzero` will be faster and if you set your initial guess, `x0`, to an upper and lower bound around the root it's guaranteed to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
auxfunc = @(u2) func(a,u2,b)
x = fsolve(auxfunc,x0)
```

You can create an auxiliary function from any function using [anonymous function expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). For this case, you substitute the first and third arguments of the function `func` with known values (`a` and `b`) to create a new function `auxfunc` that takes only one argument (`u2`). Then just put the resulting auxiliary function to `fsolve` with some initial guess `x0`.

Comment: try adding supporting details on why this solution will fix OP's problem.  As is stands, it is considered a low-quality answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

```
function main // create a main function so that you can call `func`. There is another way to do it, but it doesn't matter here.

u2_0 = 0.25; // provide an initial guess for the solution you are seeking
options = optimset('Display', 'iter'); // ask the solver to output information on the command window
[u2_opt, fval] = fsolve(@func, u2_0, options); // solve func(u2) = 0
x = -2*pi:0.1:2*pi; // plot func
plot(x, func(x), 'LineWidth', 2)
hold on
grid on
plot(u2_0, func(u2_0), 'g.', 'MarkerSize', 16) // plot the initial guess on the graph of func (green point)
plot(u2_opt, fval, 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 16) // plot the result of the solver on the graph of func (red point)
axis([-8 8 -1.25 1.25])

function y = func(u2) // define func
u1 = 1.0;
t  = 2/pi;
y = u1*cos(t*u2);
end

end
```

Schematically

[image: Demonstration of fsolve on a cosine function]

The more you read the documentation about warnings, available algorithms, parameter tuning, etc, the better. There is no solver that has completely general scope and can be blindly trusted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but my main problem was handling two extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one (scalar) variable you're better off using *fzero* than *fsolve*.